# include doesn't work, assembly tasm 8086 IDEAL mode

Tags: assembly, include, tasm

I am trying to use the include command in my code, but when I run the code (from vs code), it crushes and the error is: **Error** class.ASM(1131) Undefined symbol: DELAY
and more just like it for all the other methods (proc) in the other files, I never used include before and I have no idea why doesn't it work. help please.

the error:

```
[assembler's message] 5 Error,0  Warning collected
    Turbo Assembler  Version 4.1  Copyright (c) 1988, 1996 Borland International
    Assembling file:   JetFight.ASM
    **Error** JetFight.ASM(1108) Undefined symbol: MOVE_PLANE_DOWN
    **Error** JetFight.ASM(1112) Undefined symbol: MOVE_PLANE_RIGHT
    **Error** JetFight.ASM(1115) Undefined symbol: MOVE_PLANE_UP
    **Error** JetFight.ASM(1118) Undefined symbol: MOVE_PLANE_LEFT
    **Error** JetFight.ASM(1131) Undefined symbol: DELAY
    Error messages:    5
    Warning messages:  None
    Passes:            1
    Remaining memory:  457k
```

start of the file:

```
IDEAL

MODEL small

STACK 150h

JUMPS

DATASEG
```

the include:

```
CODESEG 

include "JetCode.asm"
```

tysm for any help!

Comment: Do not post pictures of text. Instead, copy the text into your question and surround it with [code fences](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks). Edit your question to do this.

Comment: When TASM sees the line  `include "JetCode.asm"`, it will replace this line with the contents of file "JetCode.asm".  Something in the code refers the symbols `DELAY`, `MOVE_PLANE+LEFT` etc. sooner then they were defined. Search for `DELAY` in all source files to find out.